# Getting a list of all children of a given commit

Tags: git

I'd like to run `git filter-branch` on all children of a given commit.  This doesn't seem to be an easy task, since there doesn't appear to be a way to tell `git rev-list` to only return children of a particular commit.  Using the .. syntax won't work because it will also include the parent commits of any merge within that range.  Am I missing something here?

#### edit

To clarify:  I've got a branch called `base` which has been merged into `derivative` multiple times.  I'd like to list, and eventually run `filter-branch` on, just the commits that descend from its most recent commit.  I'd also like to list similar commits on other branches.

The (simplified) situation (`derivative` is the branch on the left):

```
$ git rev-list --graph --oneline base derivative
*   f16fd151b374b2aeec8b9247489c518a6347d001 merged in the latest from the base branch
|\
| * 564d795afb63eab4ffe758dbcd726ca8b790f9f6 spelling correction
* |   2f2ed5f1d429492e1491740e30be5a58ec20af21 snogg before flarg
|\ \
| |/
| * 0c520ea33ef57b30846b122781d41fcef5e62f9b now with added flarg
* | 5068c34c3862856f511b6b4d48f2adb766e1bde4 now with added snogg
|/
* b51f227e931f830cbda042bc372087398ae7e50d initial commit
```

@araqnid's suggestion doesn't seem to work, unless I've botched reading it:

```
$ git rev-list --oneline derivative --not base
f16fd151b374b2aeec8b9247489c518a6347d001 merged in the latest from the base branch
2f2ed5f1d429492e1491740e30be5a58ec20af21 snogg before flarg
5068c34c3862856f511b6b4d48f2adb766e1bde4 now with added snogg
```

as this gives all commits in `derivative` except for the commits in `base`.  This kind of makes sense, since all it's doing is removing the ancestors of the negated commit.  What I want it to show is just the first line.

Answer (score 10):

Show the ancestry paths to commit `A` from a set of others:

> [`git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)`--ancestry-path`[`^A`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)*`others`*

Show all the unreachable commits in the repo:

> [`git fsck`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html) `--unreachable --no-reflogs \`
> `| awk '$2 == "commit" {print $3}'`

Trace all descendants of commit `A` anywhere in the repo:

```
git log --ancestry-path --graph --decorate --oneline ^A \
   --all $(git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs | awk '$2=="commit" {print $3}')
```

Git has since this answer was written learned an easier way to show all references whose history includes a commit:

```
git for-each-ref --contains A
```

to which you can add `--format='%(refname:short)'` to clean up the output.

Answer (score 5):

well, "--branches" or "--all" will include all branch tips, and then "--not A" will exclude A and all its ancestry. However, "--branches --not A" will include branches that don't include A, which I think is not what you need.

There's no easy way to get everything you want, although you can work it out. This will list all the branches containing commit A:

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads/* | while read rev type name; do
  git rev-list $rev | grep $(git rev-parse A) >/dev/null && echo $rev
done
```

then you need to list all the revisions reachable from any of those, but not A itself and any revisions back

```
git rev-list $(git for-each-ref refs/heads/* | while read rev type name; do
      git rev-list $rev | grep $(git rev-parse A) >/dev/null && echo $rev
    done) --not A
```

Note that I've only given this a very brief test :p But I think the fundamentals are sound.

Comment: I figured it would be something like that.  It seems strange that there isn't a more straightforward way to do this.  I guess this is because git commits are always linked to their parents and not their children.  I'll give it a spin and let you know how it goes.

Comment: hmm.. doesn't seem to work.  I've got a `base` (eg development) branch that's been merged multiple times into the `derivative` (eg testing) branch(es).  I want to list just the commits that are descendants of the most recent `base` commit.  However `git rev-list derivative --not base --oneline` shows me that this list includes `derivative` commits that have common ancestry with the `base` HEAD.    IE anything that has a merge from base as an ancestor.  I'll update my question to clarify this.

Comment: `git for-each-ref refs/heads/\*` doesn't include branch names with slaashes `/` in them.

Answer (score 1):

I did a alternative version. I don't know if its better or worse.

```
getGitChildren(){
    git rev-list --all --parents | grep "^.\{40\}.*${1}.*" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I commit git log -1 --oneline commit | cat -
}
```

to be  used like that:

```
$ getGitChildren 2e9df93
f210105376 feat(something): did that feature
9a1632ca04 fix(dummy): fix something
```

It just give the direct children list of a commit.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
$ for rev in $(git rev-list --branches); do
    git rev-list $rev \
      | grep $(git rev-parse base) &>/dev/null \
    && echo $rev;
  done \
  | xargs -L 1 git rev-list -n 1 --oneline
f16fd151b374b2aeec8b9247489c518a6347d001 merged in the latest from the base branch
564d795afb63eab4ffe758dbcd726ca8b790f9f6 spelling correction
```

The last pipe section with `xargs` is just to show the commit messages for each of those commits.

This lists the target commit in addition to its children, which is actually what I wanted.  It's pretty durn slow though: it took over 3 seconds to run on a 40-commit repo.  This is unsurprising since it's about as brute force as André the Giant.  I guess a more elegant method would go through the rev-list for each ref and build a tree of the hashes of each commit linked to its children, then walk it starting at the target commit.  But that's kind of complicated, so I was hoping that there was a git command for that `:)`

I still need to figure out how to get this set of commits into `filter-branch`.  I guess I can just grep the `rev-list` of `$GIT_COMMIT` from within my `--tree-filter` command.