# How can I get/list/see all the descendants of a commit with git (or gitk)?

Tags: git, parent, commit, gitk, descendant

If you use `gitk --all`, you can see all the commits of your repo, from all branches.  I want something like that except only the descendants of a given commit.

Comment: Though manojlds' first sentence is correct, it's not the entire truth: it would be possible to kludge something which checks to see if each ref has the given commit in its ancestry, and then display history starting from those refs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a list of all children of a given commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613935/getting-a-list-of-all-children-of-a-given-commit)

Answer (score 19):

I think this might do what you want. All commits in all branches, that have A as ancestor:

```
gitk --all --ancestry-path A..
```

Answer (score 9):

In short:

```
git log --all BRANCH~1..
```

In detail, with examples:  This is the complete tree of a repository I just created:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
* e3972be (HEAD, a) a-6
* 2707d79 a-5
* cdea9a7 a-4
| * 65b716e (c) c-5
| * ebe2a0e c-4
|/  
| * 2ed9abe (b) b-4
|/  
* ace558e (master) 3
* 20db61f 2
* 3923af1 1
```

Aside from `--all`, another thing is obvious: `master` -> `HEAD`:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate master..
* e3972be (HEAD, a) a-6
* 2707d79 a-5
* cdea9a7 a-4
```

So I tried combining them, and it *almost* got me what we wanted:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all master..
* e3972be (HEAD, a) a-6
* 2707d79 a-5
* cdea9a7 a-4
* 65b716e (c) c-5
* ebe2a0e c-4
* 2ed9abe (b) b-4
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't show the relationship between the branches, since the branch we're asking about was omitted.  So we have to use log from the parent of `master` like so:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all master~1..
* e3972be (HEAD, a) a-6
* 2707d79 a-5
* cdea9a7 a-4
| * 65b716e (c) c-5
| * ebe2a0e c-4
|/  
| * 2ed9abe (b) b-4
|/  
* ace558e (master) 3
```

Ta-da!  (I don't know if this simply didn't work in the past, but just in case:  I'm on git version 1.7.1)

**EDIT 2017-11-17** - Thanks to STW for actually showing the problem with this:  Independent trees would mess this up.  Commits that are entirely independent of `master` would be included in this output.  Starting from a copy of the above repo, this is what my last command would output:

```
$ git checkout --orphan z
Switched to a new branch 'z'
$ git commit --allow-empty -m'z-1'
[z (root-commit) bc0c0bb] z-1
$ git commit --allow-empty -m'z-2'
[z 1183713] z-2

$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all master~1..
* 1183713 (HEAD -> z) z-2
* bc0c0bb z-1
* 6069f73 (a) a-6
* 654d106 a-5
* a218c59 a-4
| * 338432a (c) c-5
| * 2115318 c-4
|/  
| * 43a34dc (b) b-4
|/  
* ce05471 (master) 3
```

The `z` branch, being created as an orphan, has no common history with `master`, so `z-1` and `z-2` should have been excluded but were not.  This is what `--ancestry-path` is for, I now get.  Including it will exclude branch `z`:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all --ancestry-path master~1..
* 6069f73 (a) a-6
* 654d106 a-5
* a218c59 a-4
| * 338432a (c) c-5
| * 2115318 c-4
|/  
| * 43a34dc (b) b-4
|/  
* ce05471 (master) 3
```

For completeness, even given that it already had `--ancestry-path`, the current top answer does not show the branch relationship correctly because it excludes the commit on `master` itself:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all --ancestry-path master..
* 6069f73 (a) a-6
* 654d106 a-5
* a218c59 a-4
* 338432a (c) c-5
* 2115318 c-4
* 43a34dc (b) b-4
```

Comment: I tried fiddling with variations of this, but it doesn't quite seem to show what I want [with gitk].  For example, suppose you made an intermediary child branch, and from there made 3 grandchildren branches.  What would be the way to show the gitk for just that family of branches, and none of master, or anything else?

Comment: @Pistos So using the above, I get the same output in `gitk` as `log` when I use `gitk --all master..` (as opposed to `git log --all master~1..` - So, to use a branch other than master, try `gitk --all branchname..` (include the two dots)

Comment: @Pistos I also now note that my comment has ended up almost the same as jsvnm's answer, except I don't quite understand `--ancestry-path` and why it would be necessary

Comment: Doesn't `foo..` mean `foo..HEAD` or such?  i.e. isn't that dependent on your current branch?  i.e. I want a solution that doesn't depend on the current branch being something in particular.

Comment: @Pistos Yes, but that's why we also use `--all`.  If you look at the final example in my answer, despite `HEAD` being at branch `a`, branches `b` and `c` are also visible because they are currently child branches of `master`

Comment: I'm trying this with a local repo, and --all is making it show way too much, with commits that have nothing to do with the one commit/branch that I'm trying to get descendants of.  Can you try it with a mature repo with many (hundreds) of commits, and many (20+) branches?

Comment: `--all` shows you all commits in the repository,including completely unrelated commits.

Comment: @STW Yes, and the question asked for all descendants, so `--all` is necessary to include those instead of only doing the path from branch to HEAD.  `branch~1..` then removes ancestors and unrelated descendants of those ancestors.

Comment: @Izkata -- `branch~1..` appears to exclude *older* commits, but doesn't filter out unrelated commits.   http://tpcg.io/K09v2Z

Comment: @STW Ahh, an independent tree.  I knew git could do that, but have personally never seen it in the wild.

Comment: They don't need to be independent, this command depends on chronology rather than parentage.

Answer (score 4):

A commit only knows about its parent ( and hence all the way up) but has no clue about its children / descendants. You must use a notation like A..B to find it.

For example if you want to find commits in current branch since the given commit A, you can do something like this:

```
git rev-list A..
```

Comment: `gitk --all` must work somehow.  It seems possible to at least code it to first `gitk --all` and then omit every commit that doesn't have a given commit as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this for all branches using bash/git.

This lists the descendant commits (and the given root):

```
git_list_all_descendant_hashes() {
    COMMIT=$1
    if [[ ${#COMMIT} -lt 40 ]]; then # short commit hash, need full hash
        COMMIT=`git rev-parse ${COMMIT}`
    fi

    declare -A ALL_HASHES

    while IFS= read -r string; do
        IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< $string
        key=${array[0]}
        value=${array[@]:1}
        ALL_HASHES[${key}]=$value
    done <<< $(git rev-list --children --all)

    declare -A HASHES # subset of ALL_HASHES that are descendants

    HASHES[${COMMIT}]=1

    added_hashes=1
    while [[ ${added_hashes} -gt 0 ]]; do
        added_hashes=0
        # this loop is inefficient, as it will iterate over all collected hashes each time a hash is found to have new children
        for hash in ${!HASHES[@]}; do
            for child_hash in ${ALL_HASHES[${hash}]}; do
                if [[ ! -v HASHES[$child_hash] ]]; then
                    added_hashes=1
                    HASHES[${child_hash}]=1
                fi
            done
        done
    done

    for hash in ${!HASHES[@]}; do
        echo ${hash}
    done
}
```

You can invoke it with:

```
git_descendants() {
    # the --short flag is a hack that'll return an error code if no argument is given, but git_list_all_descendant_hashes actually needs to turn it into a full hash
    COMMIT=`git rev-parse --short $1 2>/dev/null || git rev-parse HEAD`
    git log --graph --oneline --decorate ^${COMMIT}^@ $(git_list_all_descendant_hashes ${COMMIT})
}
```

If a descendant has multiple parents (i.e. from a merge commit), it'll show its non-root ancestry as well. This is something I was happy with, so I didn't bother figuring out how to get rid of it.