# Finding references to git object after history wipe

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I wiped a sensitive file from a Git repository using [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), and if I do a `git clone` I cannot, as you'd expect, find the object using something like this:

```
git rev-list --objects | grep my_filename
```

However, in an old clone I can still find the object using this technique, even though I've updated it to the best of my knowledge.  Specifically, I've run:

```
git fetch --tags --all --prune
git rebase
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

I've also deleted all branches (except master) in this clone, to no avail. I can see that some tag references the object, because:

```
git log --oneline --branches --tags -- my_filename
```

lists the commit containing the file, while:

```
git log --oneline --branches -- my_filename
```

does not (note the missing `--tags` flag in the latter), and yet explicitly enumerating all the tags:

```
for tag in $(git tag); do echo $tag; git log --oneline --branches --tags=$tag -- my_filename; done
```

turns up nothing.

My questions are:

- What is the difference between `git log --tags` and running `git log --tags=BRANCH` for every `BRANCH` in `git tag`?
- Is there a simple command to figure out why a particular object is not eligible for garbage collection by Git?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know the answer to your first question, but for

> Is there a simple command to figure out why a particular object is not eligible for garbage collection by Git?

you can find every ref that traces ancestry to a commit with

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --ancestry-path --all ^$commit
```

(and if the commit itself has a ref, do it again with `$commit^!` substituted for the `--all $commit`)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613935/getting-a-list-of-all-children-of-a-given-commit) to find even unreferenced children; for the `git fsck` output any differences between a run with `--no-reflog` and without might be interesting here.

Comment: Thank you!  That command is what I was looking for!  It tells me that the commit is pointed to by an old tag called "test2" (`* f6eea78 (tag: test2)`).

Bizarrely, however, if I explicitly list that tag in my above git log command (`--tags=test2`) it doesn't show up.  If I use a wildcard, though, (`--tags=test2*`) it does show up!

I suspect that something is wrong with the tag string itself.  It was created programmatically at some point in the past, so maybe it has some silly unprintable character in the name.  Truly strange.